# MultiIndex data frame with rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm having a hard time splitting a data frame. I am hoping to get some help.
I'm trying to split the original data into a data-frame for each city indexed in the top row and the date in the first column. For my actual data I have 189 unique cities

Original data:

[image: Original data]

This is my goal:

[image: goal]

I've tried a number of different ways but my index's are still in the first two columns.

Comment: Please provide sample data next time: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `df.pivot()`, `df.reorder_levels()` and `df.sort_index()`.

- `df.pivot()`: transpose the table into hierarchical columns

  - `axis=1` refers to columns while `axis=0` refers to rows.
- `df.reorder_levels()`: move City up and Vals down
- `df.sort_index()`: sort the rows and columns using default or customized ordering (e.g. sort as `datetime` rather than `str`).

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={  # please provide sample data next time
        "City": ["NYC"]*5 + ["LA"]*5 + ["OKC"]*5,
        "Date": ["6/1/1998", "7/1/1998", "8/1/1998", "9/1/1998", "10/1/1998"]*3,
        "Val1": np.array(range(15))*10,
        "Val2": np.array(range(15))/10,
        "Val3": np.array(range(15)),
    }
)

df_out = df.pivot(index="Date", columns=["City"], values=["Val1", "Val2", "Val3"])\
    .reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1)\
    .sort_index(axis=1)\
    .sort_index(axis=0, key=lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s))
```

**Output**:

```
In[27]: df_out
Out[27]: 

City         LA             NYC              OKC           
           Val1 Val2 Val3  Val1 Val2 Val3   Val1 Val2  Val3
Date                                                       
6/1/1998   50.0  0.5  5.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  100.0  1.0  10.0
7/1/1998   60.0  0.6  6.0  10.0  0.1  1.0  110.0  1.1  11.0
8/1/1998   70.0  0.7  7.0  20.0  0.2  2.0  120.0  1.2  12.0
9/1/1998   80.0  0.8  8.0  30.0  0.3  3.0  130.0  1.3  13.0
10/1/1998  90.0  0.9  9.0  40.0  0.4  4.0  140.0  1.4  14.0
```

N.B. If you want the "City" label on the top-left side to be removed, just set `df_out.columns.names` directly:

```
df_out.columns.names=[None, None]
```

Comment: nice answer, personally I would do `df.groupby(['Date','City']).sum().unstack(1).reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)` saves having to list all the value columns manually.

Comment: @Manakin: If there were many or variable value columns, you can list them using `[el for el in df.columns if el not in ("City", "Date")]` to avoid lengthy or data-dependent enumeration. I think this would save the cost of groupby-sum, which is logically unrelated to the true intention (pivoting the table).

Comment: Agreed, that approach is much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd

    # create an example dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(
       {'date':[1990, 2000, 2010, 2020, 1990, 2000, 2010, 2020],
       'val1': [0,1,2,3, 10,11,12,13], 
       'val2':[5,6,7,8, 50,60,70,80],
       'city':['NYC', 'NYC',  'NYC', 'NYC', 'LA', 'LA','LA', 'LA']})
    # make a pivot table with multi-index
    df2  = df.pivot(index='date', columns='city')
    # reorder the multiindex as your desired output
    df2.columns = df2.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
    df2.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, inplace=True)
    # print the dataframe
    df2
```

Output:

[image]